# Security problems with storing an internal path in a session

Tags: php

I am realising a script that will take care of storing parameters in the session. This session can be processed in completely different pages and folders than the folder and page in which it will be created. For example, if I create a session in this path:

- site > categories > subcategories

The session can be processed in this path

- site > catalogue > products

The session will thus be set up in a path

```
<?php

$_SESSION['navigation'] = array(

  'section_cod' => 'STC'

);

header('Location: ../../catalog/products/products.php');

?>
```

and thus processed in another

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['navigation'])) {

  // More code will be executed

}

?>
```

When I create a session in a path, I must also store the path in which it was created, e.g.

```
<?php

$_SESSION['navigation'] = array(

  'section_cod' => 'STC',
  'path' => __DIR__

);

header('Location: ../../catalog/products/products.php');

?>
```

But is it safe to store an internal path in a session to avoid attacks? Or should I encrypt it when storing and decrypt it when processing?

If so, are there better alternatives?

[EDIT]

I forgot to specify that I necessarily need the internal path because within the destination path I will have to include a specific file like this:

```
<?php

require $_SESSION['navigation']['path'] . '/resources/nav.php';

?>
```

Comment: Session data is not visible to anything outside your server-side code.

Answer (score -1):

Session data is stored on the server, and is normally unreachable for hackers. It is therefore save to store sensitive information in a session.

That being said, we should NOT be naive. Session IDs can be leaked, and this way sensitive information can possibly be accessed.

The only thing you can do is [read up on these things](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.session.security.management.php), and *try to understand all the risks* before you proceed. Asking us here is in no way a guarantee that your code is safe.

Comment: Even if session IDs are leaked, the session data can't be accessed if it's not sent to the client. A leaked session ID allows session hijacking, but not exposure of the data.

Comment: @Barmar You answer your own comment: When session data is sent to client in some way, it can be accessed when the session is hijacked.

Comment: Sensitive information shouldn't be sent to the client.

Comment: For instance, in this question, the path itself might not be that important, it's the PHP file that can get included this way that might be the real security risk.

Comment: @Barmer: What if a client logs in, using a session, to see their stock portfolio?

Comment: That's a general problem with using sessions at all, not specific to storing the path data.

Comment: @Barmar: Changed one word in my answer: "session" to "sensitive".

Comment: One way or another I have to store, transmit between pages and process the internal path. I can use the `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt` commands but can think of nothing else.

Comment: @webdevfp Oh no, you don't _have to_ store the path. You choose to. I'm sure there are other ways to do what you want. In programming there are almost always other ways of doing things. But as I tried to say, I wouldn't worry too much about storing the path the session. It's how you use it that is important.

Comment: I am open to other suggestions and alternatives.

Comment: You're avoiding the main point of my answer: It is your responsibility to understand what you're doing. Never rely on other programmers for the security of your own code (this may be a slight exaggeration... but in principle it is correct).

Comment: I just wanted to see if there were 'safer' alternatives to my proposal.

Comment: Just make sure your sessions can't be easily hijacked, and you should be fine. Read up on things like "JavaScript injections", "CSRF tokens", and the like. These things should be second nature to you if you actually want to secure your website.

Comment: A session can be hijacked if the attacker knows its key, in this specific case 'navigation', right?

Comment: @webdevfp: No. Sessions often use cookies. That cookie can be copied, either directly or through javascript injection. A hacker can then use that cookie to pretend to be the orginal client, accessing everything the client can access.